Create login app with Auth0 for multiple external apps
I am working for a company that collaborates with multiple external consulting firms. These consultants create applications using my company's information. The external applications must log in with Auth0 to access the information. The point is that the external applications cannot manage the users; my company has to centralize them. Therefore, I need to have a Flask application that allows these companies to access the URL, log in, and access the information. On my end, by following the Auth0 kickstart tutorial, I have already created my Flask application.
My questions are as follows:

When a successful login is generated, an "Opaque token" is returned. This does not meet the characteristics of a JWT, and the way to validate it is with "domain/userinfo." Is it correct to continue using Opaque Tokens? Is it necessary to switch to JWT Tokens? If so, how could I generate JWT Tokens?
On the other hand, I am confused about the architecture that the solution should have. Is it possible to perform the externalization as I mentioned earlier? If it is possible, is the way I am proposing correct?
On the other hand, what do Auth0 APIs have to do with it? Are they necessary for the solution I am asking about?

Thank you very much!
developed a login with a "Regular Web Application" using Flask, and I have a Flask URL that validates the Opaque Token with "domain/userinfo."

This is just a standard SSO scenario, and the ways to implement it are legion, with Auth0 or any other number of providers/libraries/frameworks/protocols.

For your first question: to use JWT or opaque totally depends on your use case buddy. As per my POV JWT token are better for authentication and i also used in my application as per how to generate JWT token follow below link
https://medium.com/@amr2018/how-to-generate-jwt-token-using-python-36c2305c5a14
As per goes the your second question : Yes, it is possible. You can have a centralized authentication system using Auth0
For your third question : yes they are necessary as auth0 api provide
Get tokens during authentication
Request a user's profile using an Access Token
Exchange Refresh Tokens for new Access Tokens
Request a challenge for multi-factor authentication (MFA)
https://auth0.com/docs/api

